# Conditionally link a third party API in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

I have a third party API that I am trying to integrate into my iOS Universal application. The API works fine if ran on a device but throws me a compile time link error when trying to run it on the simulator. So, is there a way I can skip their static library linking if I run on the simulator?

Thanks

Comment: Nope, but you can build a FAT binary that contains both the i386 code and the ARMv7 code, if you'd liek

Comment: @RichardJ.Ross:  could he possibly weak link this thing and trick Xcode into thinking it exists conditionally?

Comment: @CodaFi hmm... maybe, let me do a few tests and I'll get back to this question...

Answer (score 4):

Actually, It's a lot easier than I thought.

Step 1: Add the linker flags `-ObjC` and `-all_load` to your target. This tells the objc runtime that even if we don't reference a class in code, it will still load it into memory.

Step 2: In your code, you can do this:

```
Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"SomeClassInStaticLibrary");
if (cls == nil)
{
   // on the simulator
}
else
{
   // on the device, use the class like usual
   id myInstance = [[cls alloc] init];
}
```

Unfortunately, you have to refer to everything as an `id`, because if you include the headers, you WILL get a linker error.

Its a bit of a hack, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is build the Static Library as a `FAT` one. Compiling for both architectures armv and i386 to run in the simulator.

You can find more information about this here,

http://mark.aufflick.com/blog/2010/11/18/making-a-fat-static-library-for-ios-device-and-simulator

Comment: I actually cannot build the FAT static library as it is a third party static lib and I have no control over the code base.

Answer (score 0):

You can control this setting in the Xcode (4.3) Build Settings tab of your target. Where it talks about "Other Linker Flags" you can add a conditional setting (click and hold the lower right "+" icon that says "Add Build Setting" by default). Here you can specify the library to link using normal -l/-L linker flags but only for builds specified as "Any iOS SDK", but don't add this flag for "Any iOS Simulator SDK".

Comment: Actually, LLVM / GCC will automatically ignore any library that wasn't built for the correct architecture, but this is useful to suppress the warning. But personally, I think that the warning is useful, just so that future developers are aware that the library is only available for the device, and not the simulator.